# magento2 decrease batch size of catalog_category_product

Tags: magento2

My site contains 10k+ products and 31 stores. I want to decrease the batch size of `catalog_category_product`

How can I do that?

When I try to do that, it gives me below error:

> main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more
>   than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update
>   innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases
>   memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000;
>   Allocated memory size: 9240000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size:
>   2147483648 bytes. [] []

Answer (score 6):

Magento can increase the memory for processing a large amount of data by using memory engines instead of InnoDB. The algorithm increases the memory value for the **max_heap_table_size** and **tmp_table_size** MySQL parameters.

When the allocated memory size for a temporary table will be greater than 20% of **innodb_buffer_pool_size**, the error message is written to the Magento log.

To prevent this error message, you need to update default **Batching configuration** of catalog_category_product (Category Products) indexer because "Current batch size: 100000".

For more details, take a look [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/indexer-batch.html).

**Try following code:**

> app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="configurable" xsi:type="number">100000</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Note:**
Decrease the **batchRowsCount** to resolve the error.

Comment: i follow this but it not work for me

Comment: you descirbe how i sove this issue

Comment: @jigsparmar - Please review updated answer.

Comment: also try the below code but its not work for me

Comment: @jigsparmar - This solution only working with Magento2.2 and next upgraded versions. If you working with 2.2 and above version and still solution not working then remove var and generated folders from root and check again.

Comment: @PratikOza I got same log while reindexing. When i applied your solution i got following error, `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Indexer/BatchSizeManagement.php:49`

Comment: @Knight017 got the same error. See my answer for working code.

Comment: can add the line
<item name="default" xsi:type="number">100000</item>
Solved.
Details answer given https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/328288/26733

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me. Put it in app/code/Malpani/Harsh/etc/adminhtml/di.xml
Replace Malpani/Harsh with your module name (can be any registered module)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="number">1000</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\Price\BatchSizeCalculator">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="configurable" xsi:type="number">500</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

https://gist.github.com/harshvardhanmalpani/6528f80c117174a0edb615c93903842f

Comment: should the location be "app/code/vendor/module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml" instead of ""app/code/vendor/module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml"?

Comment: Yes @KrisWen, updated the path in my answer

Comment: can you check on this issue? thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297085/notice-undefined-index-default-in-vendor-magento-module-catalog-batchsiz

Answer (score 4):

From Magento 2.4.3, we can set the batch size with environment variables `app/etc/env.php`

For example,

```
<?php
return [
    'indexer' => [
        'batch_size' => [
            'cataloginventory_stock' => [
                'simple' => 200
            ],
            'catalog_category_product' => 666,
            'catalogsearch_fulltext' => [
                'partial_reindex' => 100,
                'mysql_get' => 500,
                'elastic_save' => 500
            ],
            'catalog_product_price' => [
                'simple' => 200,
                'default' => 500,
                'configurable' => 666
            ],
            'catalogpermissions_category' => 999,
            'inventory' => [
                'simple' => 210,
                'default' => 510,
                'configurable' => 616
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Magento docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/indexer-optimization.html

Answer (score 2):

If you look over this file.

```
vendor/magento/framework/Indexer/BatchSizeManagement.php
```

Here details are given, why the issue happened.

Now the logic is

```
if ($size > $bufferPoolSize * .2) {
   //-- Error will show
}
```

**Log warning if allocated memory for temp table greater than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size**

Point a debugger as like below picture in [xdebug CLI](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-a-php-cli-script.html).

[image]

and run

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price
```

You will found your possible problem, then you can make the solution.

**Possible Solution 1:**

For Price, the Batch Size is taken as
default argument,

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Indexer/Price/BatchSizeCalculator.php
```

Look at **estimateBatchSize** method

Now on your module add a file.

**{Your_Module_Name}/etc/di.xml.**

```
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\Price\BatchSizeCalculator">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="configurable" xsi:type="number">500</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="number">500</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**Note: Add both configurable & default argument** and the value is as per you. By default, it is 5000.

In the same way, you can change the value for others also.

**Solution 2 :**

Simply increase the **innodb_buffer_pool_size** size,

But consider the following things.

[MySQL configuration for Magento 2](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/performance-best-practices/software.html#mysql)

Answer (score 0):

On Magento 2.3.2, what worked for me was changing the file app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/adminhtml/di.xml with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="number">10000</argument>
            <argument name="batchSizeManagement" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\CategoryProductBatchSize</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Flush the cache and reindex everything.