# Getting error on re indexing in Magento 2.4 after change batch size

Tags: magento2, reindex, indexing

I have change the Batch size for Magento 2.4

```
var/www/html/Mag/app/code/Reg/Indexer/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="configurable" xsi:type="number">500</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="number">500</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

On running the indexer process it gives an error

> Category Products index PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in /var/www/html/Mag/vendor/magento/framework/Indexer/BatchSizeManagement.php:49
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/Mag/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Category/Product/Action/Full.php(269): Magento\Framework\Indexer\BatchSizeManagement->ensureBatchSize(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor), Array)
> #1 /var/www/html/Mag/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Category/Product/Action/Full.php(227): Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full->reindexCategoriesBySelect(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), 'cp.entity_id IN...', Object(Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor))
> #2 /var/www/html/Mag/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Category/Product/Action/Full.php(192): Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full->reindexRootCategory(Object(Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor))
> #3 /var/www/html/Mag/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Category/Product/Actio in /var/www/html/Mag/vendor/magento/framework/Indexer/BatchSizeManagement.php on line 49

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="number">500</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\Price\BatchSizeCalculator">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="configurable" xsi:type="number">500</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type> 
</config>
```

[Also check this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/275259/695)

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.